# Setting up RPi 2 Model B on Windows 10

Tags: pi-2, windows

Okay so I have this brand new RPi 2 Model B un-boxed and I have little idea how to set it up on Windows. I read up a bit online and downloaded putty and Nmap. On windows I'm connected to the RPi via Ethernet. In network connections, I get `Unidentified Network, No Network Access' (I don't know if this is significant). I'm not connected to the Internet.

My question:
How do I find my RPi IP address (Easy on Linux), and
How do I access the RPi terminal

Comment: Your question is unclear. Have you created a SD Card and booted the PI?

Answer (score 1):

If your RPi connected to network you may find out with [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/download/) (*supports all platforms*) and you can connect to it via [Putty](http://www.putty.org/). But first "maybe" you need to enable SSH your RPi's. If not enabled you can enable it with `raspi-config` on RPi's terminal.